# HTML input autocomplete/suggestion

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can make an input so that when the user click on it, it display all the possible values that the input can take? I can get the values from my database using php, but to display something like the image below, I guess I will have to use javascript? How can I do it?

For example, in phpPgAdmin:

[image]

Comment: This is just to involved to get a proper answer. Search for a plugin or start creating something, then ask for help on more specific coding issues.

Comment: Google search "jquery ajax autosuggest php" brought me here: http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/

Comment: what you are asking for sounds like a dropdownlist, why not simply create a dropdownlist and populate it with data from your sql database

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp Check this as a start.

Comment: Just try something and ask question.. 
What you have tried for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the select tag in HTML?  It creates a drop-down menu with options that you can load from your php script (which fetches from the database). An example from W3Schools is here:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is your best bet. The fancy styles and such are probably done with some JS - but unless you're really ready to dig in to the cross-browser issues that arise (using shims, weird form-style related things, managing the real select options while displaying divs that correspond to the select hidden in the page, etc), KISS and just use the example given here. `<?php $options = get_options(); echo "<select>"; foreach($options as $key => $val){ echo "<option value='{$key}'>{$val}</option>"; } ?>` ta-da!

Answer (score 4):

In html5, you have a new form input :

```
<input id="color" list="suggests">
<datalist id="suggests">
    <option value="Black">
    <option value="Red">
    <option value="Green">
    <option value="Blue">
    <option value="White">
</datalist>
```

If your browser doesn't support this input, you can use a polyfill as described here : http://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/

Answer (score 1):

The best plugin or the easiest to figure out would be

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I think this should be sufficient for our use case using php as backend and also has multiple customization options.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible with Ajax

**Steps :**

```
1. prepare database for such suggested values.
2. On key event run Ajax
3. Get Response of Ajax and show in list using ul li in HTML
```

**For example**

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html